# Best cross-platform solution for network server?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

im starting a new project and for the first time i want to be cross-platform. But the tricky is my project would involve listen server, cryptos etc., etc. So i was wondering what is the best solution for cross-platform development (OpenSSL, instead of MSCrypto etc.) that would be easy to write with VS2010 (yeah the RC). The language is still not specified (depends on witch we would be easier) but im leaning to Visual C++.

In Cross-Platform i mean windows/generic unix compilation.

Comment: "Best" is a red flag for possible argumentativeness on this explicitly subjective question. You should probably supply a set of objective criteria for evaluating the candidates lest this get closed.

Comment: Yeah you're right better find this my own way, instead using questionable advices.

Answer (score 2):

Qt4 is a complete crossplatform framework, including a very strong socket library.
also Boost.Asio http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/libraries.htm.

Answer (score 0):

The [Poco C++](http://pocoproject.org/) library may be what you are looking for.